Getting buffer_info from py::memoryview
Using Pybind11, is there a way to get the py::buffer_info object from a py::memoryview? Or some other way to get the data pointer, number of dimensions, shape, strides, item size from the python memoryview, without creating a copy of the array?
It is for a function that takes a py::memoryview as parameter, so that it can be called from Python with a memoryview object.
The underlying Python C API seems to have PyMemoryView_GET_BUFFER() for this, but it is not wrapped anywhere by pybind.
